# delete query error(null) ( .net core, angular 5)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

i want delete object from database.

My conttroller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult del([FromBody] string p1)
        {
            try
            { 
              if (p1 != null)
              {
                RaschetDoppokazR1 obj = db.RaschetDoppokazR1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.P1 == p1);
                if (obj != null)
                   {
                      db.RaschetDoppokazR1.Remove(obj);
                      db.SaveChanges();
                      return Json("OK");
                   }
                else return Json("doesnt exist");
              }
              else return Json("null");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return Json("Exception");
            }
        }
```

and angular query:

```
this.http.post('api/data/del', e.data.p1 as string , {responseType: 'json',
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          })  
        })
         .subscribe(data => (console.log(data)));
```

i have response : "null". If i dont note Content-Type as "application/json", i get error : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoEMr.jpg)

Tell please, what i do wrong? Thanks.

Update:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult add_RaschetDoppokazR1([FromBody] RaschetDoppokazR1[] obj)
    {
        try
        { 
          if (obj != null)
          {
            db.RaschetDoppokazR1.AddRange(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("ok");
          }
          else return Json("null");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return Json("exception");
        }
    }
```

and angular request:

```
this.http.post('api/data/add_RaschetDoppokazR1', JSON.stringify(this.tabl1.filter(x => x.id == null) as RaschetDoppokazR1[]),
            {   headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              })  
            })
            .subscribe(data => (console.log(data)));
```

agian i get null

Comment: It's probably because you are filtering the items that are null...

Comment: Hello, i filtering objects, where id == null. Its not null request body

Comment: i am send RaschetDoppokazR1[] object. Need i out JSON.stringify or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string to the body but you are saying that it's a Content Type of `application/json"

What you need to do is to put json in the body:

```
this.http.post('api/data/del', JSON.stringify(e.data.p1 as string) , {responseType: 'json',
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          })  
        })
         .subscribe(data => (console.log(data)));
```

Comment: Its work, thanks a lot! I have one similar question( in edit), help please